# Random Character in map in DynamoDB

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, aws-sdk

When I update some record in DynamoDB as such

```
UpdateExpression: "set #audioField = :payload",
ExpressionAttributeValues: {
              ":payload": something,
          },

var something = {"test.com1": {}}
```

DynamoDB puts a random character in the record like this

```
{ "test.com1" : { "M" : { } }}
```

What's up with this? And how do I prevent this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not a random character, this is how DynamoDB stores and represents types.

DynamoDB embeds type information in each value that is stores.  See the following for the list of types: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/APIReference/API_AttributeValue.html

Based on the linked above, The `"M"` that you are seeing is describing the contents of "test.com1" attribute which is a map (M for map).

The reason you are not seeing these in your other attributes is probably because the SDK is automatically translating this DynamoDB structure into native types for the top-level attributes but not for nested attributes.

What language/SDK are you using?  Many SDKs have helpers that you can pass your results through to parse these embedded types and convert them into native types that are easier to work with.

Comment: Thank you for the reply! I am using Javascript / Node.js and 'aws-sdk'. Do you know how to disable this automatic translation into native types?

Comment: Check out the [output and unmarshall functions in the Javascript SDK](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/DynamoDB/Converter.html)

Comment: I don't really understand why Amazon does this. What is the point of this?? if I want to update something now do I have to do 

UpdateExpression: "SET #something.M.#payload.S.#type = "wow""?

Comment: could you look at this question please?? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56318816/dynamodb-overriding-existing-key-value-pair-due-to-attributevalues
I need some serious help understanding DynamoDB,, it is very different from MongoDB although they are both NoSQL

Comment: @MattChoi they made some early architectural decisions, presumably, to work around different languages handling data types in their own random ways.  You probably should take a look at the [DynamoDB DocumentClient](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/DynamoDB/DocumentClient.html) if that isn't what you are using now.