# DynamoDB overriding existing key value pair due to AttributeValues

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, aws-sdk

----------------- GIVING MORE CONCRETE EXAMPLES BELOW -----------------

I have the following function, where I take user, name, sex from parameters and update the existing client for that user.

```
function createRecord(user, personName, sex) {
  var sexPayload = [];
  var dynamoParams = {
    TableName: 'account',
    Key: {
      id: user
    },
    UpdateExpression: "set #client.#person.#sex = :sexPayload",
    ExpressionAttributeNames: {
      "#client": "client",
      "#person": personName,
      "#sex": sex
    },
    ExpressionAttributeValues: {
        ":sexPayload": sexPayload,
    },
    ConditionalExpression: "attribute_not_exists(#client.#person.#sex)"
  };
  docClient.update(dynamoParams, function(err, data){
    something...
  });
}
```

if personName = "John" sex = "man", 
this creates

```
client: {
    John: {"M": {"man": {"L": []}}},
}
```

and when I pass in another name = "John" sex = "female",
this overrides existing John "man" and writes "female" under John

```
client: {
    John: {"M": {"female": {"L": []}}},
}
```

What I want to achieve is this:

```
client: {
    John: {"M": {"man": {"L": []}, {"female": {"L": []}},
}
```

what am I doing wrong??

Comment: can you provide a more complete example of your code that updates the field names/variables?

Comment: I provided more concrete example of what I am trying to achieve. Thank you for the help by the way!